# You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (4.0.3)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-scripts

After run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

and then `npm install -g create-react-app` I still get the same message and `create-react-app` version is not updated. I also tried `npm install -g create-react-app@4.0.3`, but don't get my solution. Now I am unable to create any react CLI app. How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: It helps to actually read the text you're showing others. The notice _literally_ tells you what to do: uninstall the global create-react-app, and then go to that URL to read how to use create-react-app now that global installs are no longer supported. Also, remember to follow the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). Do not post images of text: put that text in your post.

Comment: but  `yarn global remove create-react-app` not remove the `create-react-app` package.

Comment: And that's where reading the text still matters: it says to use "one of the following", not to run both. If you installed it with `npm`, then you need to uninstall it with `npm`, and if you installed it with `yarn`, you need to uninstall it with `yarn`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app
```

Answer by BenJenkinson here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10601

Answer (score -1):

Instead of globally installing create react app use `npx create-react-app`

Even react advises you not to install it globally as quoted from their [readme](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#create-react-app--) of create react app.

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Comment: Yeah: it advises them _right in the notice they're showing in their post_. This didn't need an answer, this needed a "please do what the text is telling you to do".